# Зарезервированные слова в качестве названия столбца

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю SQL запрос в базу:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO faq (name, desc, pos) VALUES ($a, $b, $c)';
```

Как видно из запроса, в таблице есть поле `desc` и в него нужно поместить текст, НО язык SQL определяет этот момент в запросе не как поле, а как команду `DESC` (для сортировки по убыванию). Соответственно запрос не выполняется, и у меня белый экран! Ибо если преименовать это поле к примеру в `descr` (и в базе соответственно) то все работает.. Но мне нужно что бы это поле называлось именно так..
Отсюда и вопрос, что мне сделать, что бы слово `desc` определялось как поле, а не как команда?

Comment: Заключайте имя поля в обратные апострофы, вот такие \`desc\` (но тогда начинает быть важен еще и регистр, так что убедитесь что оно создалось именно маленькими буквами)

Comment: насколько знаю, использовать в названиях зарезервированные слова - плохая практика.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, там немаленький список, чтобы всё запомнить https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Comment: @КириллМалышев nfv 70% таких слов, что вряд ли когда то придет в голову так назвать столбец. 29% и так используешь в быту, поэтому знаешь их. и на 1% при ошибке говоришь "ого, а это что за штука" и идешь читать для общего развития.

Answer (score 1):

Для обозначения полей в MySQL используются символ [машинописный обратный апостроф](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84)

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `faq` (`name`, `desc`, `pos`) VALUES (?, ?, ?);';
```